# React native styled components tintColor not working properly

Tags: css, react-native, styles, styled-components, react-native-ui-kitten

This works fine(the icon is white and has the correct size):

```
// Logo definition
import { Icon } from '@ui-kitten/components'

const Logo = props => <Icon {...props} name='logo' pack='app' />

// index.js

  <Logo style={{
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    tintColor: theme["basic-color-100"]
  }}/>
```

Then, I turned the element into a styled-component:

```
// index.js:

    <StyledLogo />

// styles.js

    export const StyledLogo = styled(Logo)`
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      tint-color: ${({theme}) => {theme["basic-color-100"]}
    `
```

NOTE: if I change StyledLogo's color using inline style, it doesn't work neither

tint-color property is now completely ignored (the icon has the right size, but is completely black). How can I solve it?

Comment: Is the problem `tint-color` or use of the UI Kitten? If you use `tint-color: red;` does it change your icon to red?

Comment: No, it doesn't change(I infer you are referring to StyledLogo in styles.js). I don't know if the problem involves tint-color or UI Kitten. I believe it is more probable that it involves styled and tint-color